# Using an Array.prototype.forEach in AngularJS not updating to the view

Tags: angularjs, foreach, angularjs-scope

I have a piece of code inside an angular controller that requests three services for data. Once the last service returns, I'm taking the data from all and merge it into a dataset. Out of the nested loops, my "vm" instance of this have the values I want the way I want (using a $log.debug to the console) but when I try to access in the view it has the value of initialization.
Here is my code:

```
function loadConfigs(userId) {
  // Load the apps the user have access to
  aimsApps.getAccessibleApps()
  .then((resApps) => {
    vm.apps = resApps.data;

    // Load notifications types
    aimsNotificationTypes.getNotificationTypes()
    .then((resTypes) => {
      vm.types = resTypes;

      // Load the configurations for a user
      aimsNotificationConfigs.getNotificationConfigs(userId)
      .then((resConfigs) => {
        vm.configs = resConfigs;

        // Create a store like notification[app][type] and load the configs
        $log.debug('ALL RESOLVED', vm.apps, vm.types, vm.configs);
        vm.apps.forEach((eApp) => {
          vm.notifSettings[eApp.name] = [];
          vm.types.forEach((eType) => {
            vm.configs.forEach((eConfig) => {
              if ((eConfig.app === eApp.name) && (eConfig.notificationType === eType.name)) {
                vm.notifSettings[eApp.name][eType.name] = eConfig;
              } else {
                vm.notifSettings[eApp.name][eType.name] = {
                  app: eApp.name,
                  user: userId,
                  notificationType: eType.name,
                  sendToWeb: true,
                  sendToEmail: true,
                  sendToSMS: true,
                };
              }
            });
          });
        });

        $log.debug('NOTIF CONFIG', vm.notifSettings);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

When this line `$log.debug('NOTIF CONFIG', vm.notifSettings);` is reached, I can see in the console the values for `vm.notifSettings` but my view doesn't reflect those changes.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you create a plunker to demonstrate the problem. I think the issue must be linked on how you assign the variable vm.settings to your template.

It is possible that you loose the reference to vm.settings

Comment: I assume you are creating vm.notifSettings[eApp.name] = []; array in the for each loop ? If so then it is not the way how you do it. As you are creating a scope object outside angular context and that too in http call.I would suggest to create your scope object outside service call and reset at the start of the loop